# How can I display korean in moviepy?

Tags: python, video, cjk, moviepy

**My code:**

```
#-- coding:utf-8 --
from moviepy.editor import *

myclip = VideoFileClip("55.mp4").subclip(10,40)
t = u'55 도발'.encode('utf-8')
txtclip = TextClip(t, fontsize=50, color='red', font='NanumGothic').set_duration(5)
file = CompositeVideoClip([myclip, txtclip.set_pos(('center', 'bottom'))])

file.write_videofile('text.mp4')
```

In `text.mp4`, video display just `55`, it ignore `도발`.

How can I fix it?